# Different implementations of decorators in python

Tags: python, decorator

Sorry for long question, but I don't know how to make it shorter.

## 1. Decorators without args

### Implementation 1.1 (through function)

```
import time
import functools

def pause(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(1)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@pause
def func(x, y):
    """desc"""
    return x + y

print func(1, 2)
help(func)
```

Output:

```
3
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(*args, **kwargs)
    desc
```

It's "classical" implementation - a lot of articles contain it.

-breaks function signature (can be solved by nonstandard module decorator)

-you must use functools for saving name and doc string of function (not very big problem, but slightly more code and magic)

+you can modify function args (not always necessary)

+-? Anything else?

### Implementation 1.2 (through function)

```
import time

def pause(f):
    time.sleep(1)
    return f

@pause
def func(x, y):
    return x + y

print func(1, 2)
help(func)
```

Output:

```
3
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(x, y)
    desc
```

? Why it implementation rarely used in articles and examples? What have I missed?

-you can't modify function args

+not breaks function signature

+less code

+-? Anything else?

### Implementation 1.3 (through classes)

```
import time

class pause(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(1)
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

@pause
def func(x, y):
    """desc"""
    return x + y

print func(1, 2)
help(func)
```

Output:

```
3
Help on pause in module __main__ object:

class pause(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
 |  
 |  __init__(self, f)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

IMHO, ugly.

### Implementation 1.4 (through classes)

```
import time

class pause(object):
    def __call__(self, f):
        time.sleep(1)
        return f

@pause()
def func(x, y):
    """desc"""
    return x + y

print func(1, 2)
help(func)
```

Output:

```
3
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(x, y)
    desc
```

-you can't modify function args

-nonstandard syntax for decorator use

+not breaks function signature

+-less code (but more than implementation 2 :) )

+-? Anything else?

## 2. Decorators with args

### Implementation 2.1 (through function)

```
import time
import functools

def pause(t):
    def wrapper(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
            time.sleep(t)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return tmp

    return wrapper

@pause(1)
def func(x, y):
    """desc"""
    return x + y

print func(1, 2)
help(func)
```

Output:

```
3
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(*args, **kwargs)
    desc
```

It's "classical" implementation - a lot of articles contain it.

-breaks function signature

-nested is worse than flat

-you must use functools for saving name and doc string of function

+you can modify function args

+-? Anything else?

### Implementation 2.2 (through function)

```
import time

def pause(t):
    def wrapper(f):
        time.sleep(t)
        return f
    return wrapper

@pause(1)
def func(x, y):
    """desc"""
    return x + y

print func(1, 2)
help(func)
```

Output:

```
3
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(x, y)
    desc
```

? Why it implementation rarely used in articles and examples? What have I missed?

-you can't modify function args

+not breaks function signature

+less code

+-? Anything else?

### Implementation 2.3 (through classes)

```
import time

class pause(object):
    def __init__(self, darg):
        self.darg = darg
    
    def __call__(self, f):
        time.sleep(self.darg)
        return f

@pause(1)
def func(x, y):
    """desc"""
    return x + y

print func(1, 2)
help(func)
```

Output:

```
3
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(x, y)
    desc
```

-you can't modify function args

+not breaks function signature

+-less code (but more than implementation 2 :) )

IMHO+ little clearer than nested functions

+-? Anything else?

## Questions in one place

1. Why implementations 1.1/2.1 are more common in articles and examples as compared with implementations 1.2/2.2?
2. What are the pros and cons I missed?
3. Did I missed something else?

Comment: *Sorry for long question, but I don't know how to make it shorter.* - A shorter version could have been "What are the different ways of creating decorators in Python, and what are their pros and cons?". The rest of your question could then be posted as an answer to this shorter question.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Heh, but I have questions also ;)

Comment: I think you're making an artificial distinction between 1.4 & 2.3.

Comment: @martineau: Yes, of course. In fact 1.4 is a special case of 2.3. I considered the differences only within task: or decorator without args, or decorator with args.

Comment: The decorator in Implementation 1.2 executes right after the function it is applied to has been compiled which it just returns and otherwise has no effect on it -- so that function will run no differently than if it hadn't been used at all. It's hard to think how that could be useful, which might be why you don't see it too often.

Comment: @martineau: Thanks. I already knew. In fact, in my post overlapped misunderstanding and a bad example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is good that the implementations 1.2 & 2.2 are "less common than" 1.1 and 2.1, because they do different things. In fact, I wouldn't call them "decorators", because they don't really wrap ("decorate") the function. Instead, they only perform their action once, at the moment the decorated function is parsed.  That is, their action (sleep in your case) is performed at function definition time, not at function invocation time.

Try invoking your decorated functions several times and you will see the difference.

Comment: +1 This. Nearly identical to what I wanted to post. (Applies to 2.3 too)

Comment: I totally disagree (but not worth a downvote). Every decorator only performs it's action once, at function definition time. Some of them happen to wrap the function, some register it with some registry and some replace it entirely but they all do it only once and immediately after definition. I think that what you mean is that they are not instances of the decorator design pattern but it's old news that python decorators go well beyond that.

Comment: @aaronasterling: But for "normal" decorators, the action performed once at decoration time is replacing the decorated function with a function that performs additional actions at call time. This *is* an important difference, and although things like adding the function to a registry instead of replacing it are valid use cases and done from time to time, it's indeed "less common". One can argue that these are decorators too (in fact, I agree), but apart from that, this answer is correct.

Comment: @Gintautas Miliauskas: Thanks.

Comment: Aaron, you're right. Indeed sometimes decorators only, say, register the function in a registry, I use them that way sometimes too. I guess while I was answering my mind got stuck in the context of the example where the sleep() was clearly intended for runtime, not decoration time. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I have another question that I forgot to ask. I do not know whether to create a separate question, or better to ask here.

Why functools.wraps doesn't restore function signature? Is this a position of developers? Or is it a defect? If yes, there is an issue about this on http://bugs.python.org? I could not find anything similar...

Comment: What do you mean by "restoring function signature"? You may want to ask this question separately.

Comment: @Gintautas Miliauskas: for example in 1.1: help(func) return "func(*args, **kwargs)" not "func(x, y)". It can be fixed by using nonstandard module decorator. But it is external dependence...